# convert function from Access SQL to T-SQL 2005

Tags: t-sql, ms-access, function

Can someone please convert this access sql function for me to work in t-sql 2005.

I am tring to take the selling price minus the cost as one number. And divide that by the original selling price to produce a second number

Thanks :)

```
 =IIf([Selling Price]=0,0,([Selling Price]-Nz([Cost]))/[Selling Price])
```

IIRC it should be something along the lines of;

```
ISNULL((ISNULL([Selling Price],0) - ISNULL(Cost,0)),0) / ISNULL([Selling Price],0) AS Margin
```

But here I am getting a divide by Zero error.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL([Selling Price],0) = 0 THEN 0
        ELSE ([Selling Price] - ISNULL([Cost],0))/[Selling Price]
    END AS fieldName
FROM TableName
```

Comment: accepted as most elegant and easy to understand. Thanks very much. I think this was the first. Cheers everyone else :)

Comment: it wasn't quite the first ;) but nice one anyway.

Comment: @Andrew - It may read a little nicer, but it doesn't cover the situation where [Selling Price] = 0

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE 
   WHEN ISNULL([Selling Price], 0) = 0 THEN 0
   ELSE ([Selling Price] - ISNULL([Cost], 0)) / [Selling Price] 
END
```